# Create multiple shapes dynamically in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

This is code that I use. I am trying to dynamically create multiple shapes and create animation (function drawLine) with them. I have result shows me only one animation(first one) and then nothing. It should be 6 animation. I think that addChild() function is not creating multiple shapes as I wanted.

```
  import flash.display.Shape;

var startPoint:Point = new Point();
var endPoint:Point = new Point();

var prog:Number = 0;
var bonus:Number = 1;
var frames:int = 150;

var numbers:Array = new Array();

numbers[0] = new Array();
numbers[0][0] = 460;
numbers[0][1] = 100;

numbers[1] = new Array();
numbers[1][0] = 10;
numbers[1][1] = 20;

numbers[2] = new Array();
numbers[2][0] = 10;
numbers[2][1] = 100;

numbers[3] = new Array();
numbers[3][0] = 10;
numbers[3][1] = 180;

numbers[4] = new Array();
numbers[4][0] = 160;
numbers[4][1] = 20;

numbers[5] = new Array();
numbers[5][0] = 160;
numbers[5][1] = 100;

numbers[6] = new Array();
numbers[6][0] = 160;
numbers[6][1] = 180;

numbers[7] = new Array();
numbers[7][0] = 310;
numbers[7][1] = 20;

numbers[8] = new Array();
numbers[8][0] = 310;
numbers[8][1] = 100;

numbers[9] = new Array();
numbers[9][0] = 310;
numbers[9][1] = 180;

var fullDate:String = "271524";

var i:Number;
var pom:Number;
var shapes:Vector.<Shape> = new Vector.<Shape>();
for (i=0; i < fullDate.length; i++){

    pom = int(fullDate.charAt(i));
    shapes[i] = new Shape();
    addChild(shapes[i]);

    trace(numbers[pom+1][0]);
    drawLine(numbers[pom][0], numbers[pom][1], numbers[pom+1][0], numbers[pom+1][1], 120);
}

function drawLine(startX:Number, startY:Number, endX:Number, endY:Number, time:Number = 120):void {
    startPoint.x = startX;
    startPoint.y = startY;
    endPoint.x = endX;
    endPoint.y = endY;

    frames = time;
    prog = 0;
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tick);
}

function drawLineTick(progress:Number):void{
    for each(var shape:Shape in shapes)
    {
        shape.graphics.clear();
        shape.graphics.lineStyle(14,0x2dfdfd);

        shape.graphics.moveTo(startPoint.x,startPoint.y);
        shape.graphics.lineTo(startPoint.x + ((endPoint.x - startPoint.x) * progress), startPoint.y + ((endPoint.y - startPoint.y) * progress));

    }

}

function tick(e:Event):void {
    if(prog >= frames){
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tick);
    }

    drawLineTick(prog / frames);    
    prog += bonus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `s` only refers to the last `Shape` you created.  Try something like this: (at the moment, all the shapes are on top of each, so you won't see multiple animations, but you can adjust that)

```
fullDate = "174689";
var shapes:Vector.<Shape> = new Vector.<Shape>();
for (i=0; i < fullDate.length; i++){
    pom = int(fullDate.charAt(i));

    shapes[i] = new Shape();
    addChild(shapes[i]);
    drawLine(numbers[pom][0], numbers[pom][1], numbers[pom+1][0], numbers[pom+1][1], 50);
}


function drawLine(startX:Number, startY:Number, endX:Number, endY:Number, time:Number = 120):void {
    startPoint.x = startX;
    startPoint.y = startY;
    endPoint.x = endX;
    endPoint.y = endY;

    frames = time;
    prog = 0;
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tick);
}

function drawLineTick(progress:Number):void{
    for each(var shape:Shape in shapes)
    {
        shape.graphics.clear();
        shape.graphics.lineStyle(14,0x2dfdfd);

        shape.graphics.moveTo(startPoint.x,startPoint.y);
        shape.graphics.lineTo(startPoint.x + ((endPoint.x - startPoint.x) * progress), startPoint.y + ((endPoint.y - startPoint.y) * progress));

    }

}

function tick(e:Event):void {
    if(prog >= frames){
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tick);
    }

    drawLineTick(prog / frames);    
    prog += bonus;
}
```

Comment: I updated my ActionScript, so you can see complete code, after your implementation. It still shows the same result as it was. Just the first animation is shown. Could you guess what is wrong with the script. I am sure is not much complicate, but I can't find solution. Thanks